# Running a click event once you add a class to a div - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I came across an issue when working on a open/close navigation.  I have the button hide and once that is clicked it will first, add the new class; than remove the original one.  Than, once open is clicked the reverse will happen.  The issue is when trying to run a click event on the open section, nothing happens?

Example:

```
 <div class="hideNshow">
   <span><a href="#" onclick="return false">Hide</a></span>
 </div><!-- .hideNshow -->
```

Now once `.hideNshow` is clicked, the new class will be `.openNav` - the issue is using a click event in a ready statement to check if `.openNav` is clicked will not run.

I am not to sure what is wrong here:

Thoughts and suggestions would be appreciated.

David

EDIT

Here is the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var active = 0;
    var lastheight, lastMargin, lastmargintop;

    $(".open").click(function() {
        alert("working");
            $("#mainHead").css('height', lastheight);   
            $(".openNav").html("Hide");
            $(".openNav").css('margin-top', lastMargin);    
            $(".about").css('margin-top',lastmargintop);
            $(".openNav").addClass("hideNshow");
            $(".hideNshow").removeClass("openNav");
    });
    $(".hideNshow").click(function() {
            lastheight = $("#mainHead").height();
            lastMargin = $(".hideNshow").css('margin-top'); 
            lastmargintop = $(".about").css('margin-top');  
            $("#mainHead").css('height', '35px');   
            $(".hideNshow").html("Open");
            $(".hideNshow").css('margin-top', '-30px'); 
            $(".about").css('margin-top','45px');
            $(".hideNshow").addClass("openNav");
            $(".openNav").removeClass("hideNshow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because when you use normal event handlers, those are added to only those elements which satisfies the selector when the registration code is executed - in your case when the page is loaded the div may have the `hideShow` class only so only that handler will be added.

If you want the selector to be evaluated lazily then use the event deletation

You need to use event delegation

```
//use document or any other immediate parent of the div
$(document).on('click', '.hideNshow', function(){
    //handle hide
})
//use document or any other immediate parent of the div
$(document).on('click', '.openNav ', function(){
    //handle show
})
```

Comment: I did not think i would have to do this, any reason as to why?

Comment: @DavidBiga see the explanation